# Security model (deployment) for MS Access application with SQL Server Backend

Tags: sql-server, security, ms-access, deployment, sql-server-express

We have an application, consisting of an MS Access frontend (2007, mdb format), a few .net libraries and an SQL Server (2008) backend. I am working on an installer, which automatically installs the MS Access Runtime, our application, our libraries, SQL Server Express and configures everything.

Clearly, the MS Access application and the libraries (running in a normal, **non-admin user context**) need access to the SQL Server database. **What is the best way to grant access to the application?**

---

This is what I came up with. Unfortunately, all of these seem to have drawbacks:

- **SQL Server Compact Edition**: Does not support views.
- **[Application Roles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190998.aspx)**: This seems to be *best practice*. However, it requires executing a stored procedure before accessing the database (I cannot pass the app credentials in the connection string). Thus, I cannot use this to [attach the SQL Server tables as a linked tables in the Access MDB](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/tables/link_table2007.php), which is a requirement of our Access application.
- **[SQL Server User Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143684.aspx)**: To quote from MSDN: "*This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using this feature in new development work...*"
- **[SQL Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx)**: Microsoft says: "*When possible, use Windows Authentication.*"
- **Using Windows authentication and granting BUILTIN\USERS full access**: This is by far the easiest solution, but somehow it "seems wrong" to do that...

The application is targeted at a non-technical audience, so asking the user to configure permissions is not an option.

EDIT: Some clarification: It's a "local" application, i.e., the SQL Server is located on the same machine as the application; SQL Server access from the network is neither necessary nor desired. The software (a regular business application for managing stocks, invoices, etc.) will be available to download for free, so it should run in a variety of environments (domain/non-domain, different operating systems, etc.), and IT knowledge should not be required to install it -- apart from the usual "click on setup.exe, confirm UAC prompt, acknowledge the installation directory, etc.". I expect the most common scenarios to be "Windows XP, local admin user" and "Windows Vista/7, local admin user with UAC enabled". Since we want to follow good practices, *running* the application should not require "Run as Administrator" in the latter case.

Comment: Are the client and the database server on the same machine? Are we talking of a 'one-to-one' situation, where each user has his own server located on his machine? Are the machines in a Domain? Does the user have a password to start/unlock his machine? How does the user install the software pack on his machine if he is not an administrator?

Comment: @Philippe: I've updated the question. The user will install the application by double-clicking on setup.exe and acknowledging the UAC prompt. ;-) Running the application (and, thus, accessing the SQL Server DB) should not require elevation, however.

Answer (score 1):

@Heinzi write:

> Using Windows authentication and
>   granting BUILTIN\USERS full access:
>   This is by far the easiest solution,
>   but somehow it "seems wrong" to do
>   that...

The usual approach here is to add a custom user group (e.g., "db-users") and put the users in that group. That way you can control exactly who is allowed access.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Indeed, that's the solution I'd choose as a system administrator. The problem is that the software should be a downloadable end-user product, i.e. the target group includes people who have no idea what a "user group" is...

Comment: In that case, SQL Server authentication and SQL Server roles seem to me to be the way to go, no?

Comment: Yes, that will probably be it. I was just wondering if there's anything wrong with this approach, since I had the feeling that SQL authentication is considered a bit "outdated" nowadays.

Comment: I find Windows authentication a lot easier, but in your distribution scenario, you have different considerations, so I don't think it's inappropriate.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

- Use an Access ADP project, pre-configured to connect to the locally installed SQL Server instance.
- Connect using BuiltIn\Users group (or SQL authentication) but grant only the bare minimum credentials. Enough to logon and ...
- Call sp_setappprole to "elevate" the client connection to your defined application role's identity.

Comment: Yep, that's definitely the way to go if we used ADPs instead of MDBs. Unfortunately, ADP projects are not an option, since our code requires some of the mdb features, such as local querydefs. As Microsoft recommends *not* using ADPs but MDBs or ACCDBs with linked tables (quote: "The preferred way to connect to SQL Server is MDB file format or ACCDB file format.", http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc178973.aspx), I don't think that we will migrate our application to an ADP project.

Comment: What are you using local Querydefs for that ADPs can't support?

Wow, its a huge shame that Microsoft is seemingly downplaying ADPs. IMO, its is the ideal development technology for most workgroup sized applications...

Comment: Well, I guess the application could be rewritten into an ADP (querydefs are used mostly as adaptable report sources), but the querydef thing is just one of the issues. We tried ADP some years ago and I don't remember all the details, but the conclusion was that an awful lot of legacy code would need to be rewritten. Thus, it is not an option at the moment.

Comment: Yeah, I was about to suggest various ways of working around the lack of querydefs. But now I see there's a dependency on legacy code that would require alot of re-work to use in ADPs. Oh well...

Comment: Even without legacy code, ADPs were always a moving target. Each version had its own set of gotchas, and they changed from version to version (A2002 fixed bugs in A2000 ADPs, but introduced its own, and then A2003 reverted some of the fixed bugs while introducing its own). ADPs were simply a failed idea that were probably a waste of time from the beginning. Conceptually it might have worked, but never reached that "version 3" completeness that MS is renowned for.

Answer (score 1):

If sound like you have only got the tie of the iceberg.  When it comes to selling and deploying access SQL applications.

I have take a different route.  I have virtual computers as standalone workstation and domain server and workstation all virtual.

I have write a scripts they are a combination of VBA and VBScript.
Ask 
Is the DB and App to run on single computer or different computers.
     If different computer what is the name of the computer the DB is located on.
Is the DB and App to in a workgroup, homegroup or domain environment
Is the DB computer already have SQL Express or above
Is the App computer already have Access or Access Runtime installed.
     If yes which version.
Will all or only limited users have access.
     If limited what is the user group name of user to be have access to the data.
     Does this group already exist
           If No List the Name of the Users that Should Be Added to the Group
Also questions about the Admin Users and Group

The script start the virtual machines and goes through a series of steps to rep the MDB and SQL DB for deployment. Then creates an MSI for the Server Install with include a custom script that sets up the environment.  Finally packages MDB in a nice MSI.

I have since enhanced the process to allow some questions to be answered at the beginning of the server installation.   This means the user groups and users can be selected from the lists in the workstation or domain depending on prior questions asked.

If user the app user is a member of the Admin Group of the Workstation or Domain. They get extra menu options. That allow them to add or remove members from the DB user group for the workstation or domain.  This I find is helpful.

I am now moving to the next stage and looking at hosting my assess app as an SasS (Software as a Service) (Rental).  So the app can be use in any HTML5 Browser, Windows or Mac as Virtual Desktop or Android and Apple device.  Having said that Access is a bit ugly on mobile devices.

When I am up and running I will make the platform available to others.